# Calling a non static method using blazor interop from js

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop

Working on a blazor application, it has a method that needs to be called from the JS ! When I try to call the method without static keyword I get this error  -

```
 The assembly 'AssemblyName' does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute("INIT_COMPLIANCE")].
```

As soon as I add static it recognizes and loads it fine.

Here's my code in blazor component -

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        jsToDotNetBridgeReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        js.InvokeVoidAsync("SetDotNetReference", jsToDotNetBridgeReference);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


[JSInvokableAttribute("INIT_COMPLIANCE")]
public async void InitComplianceComponent(string token)
{
    id_token = token;
    Console.WriteLine(token);
    await GetData();
}
```

JS -

```
 self.addNewCompliance = function () {
        const url = someurl;
        var resource = window.authContext.getResourceForEndpoint(url);
        window.authContext.acquireToken(resource, function (error, token) {
            // Handle ADAL Error
            if (error || !token) {
                console.log('ADAL Error Occurred: ' + error);
                return;
            } else {
                Blazor.start().then(() => {
                    window.InitComplianceComponent(window.DotNet, token); 
                })
                //window.InitComplianceComponent(window.DotNet, token);
            }
        });
    }
```

BlazorInterop.js

```
 InitComplianceComponent = function (dotnetObj, token) {
        dotnetObj.invokeMethod("AssemblyName", "INIT_COMPLIANCE", token);
        
    }
```

I do not want to use static keyword as the `GetData` is non-static method and I cannot call it from the static method.

Where am I wrong here.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#invoke-an-instance-net-method-1)

Comment: HI, Yes I read through it, but I am having tough time understanding the call of non static method. Can u help me through what I am missing ! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("yourJsFunctionName", 
    DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), nameof(MethodToInvokeFromJs));
}

[JSInvokable]
public void MethodToInvokeFromJs()
{
    //your code
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

and your js code will look like this:

```
function yourJsFunctionName(instance, callback) {
    instance.invokeMethodAsync(callback);
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked ! Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: what would it look like if we wanted to send an argument from JS to Blazor function? and wanted to return a value back to the JS function from Blazor function?

Comment: you can do something like this on your js function, `instance.invokeMethodAsync(callback, "argument from js").then(returnedValueFromCS => console.log(returnedValueFromCS));`. If you want a detailed answer ask a separate question.